# Report to Multiple Google Analytics Property IDs?

Tags: google, html, javascript, analytics

Is it possible to have Google Analytics report traffic to a given page to more than one Profile ID? If so, are there any special considerations or recommendations for doing such? I can't seem to find anything about doing this in the Analytics documentation.

Can I just call `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);` multiple times? Or would the *nth* call just override the previous one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the UA-xxxxx id is different I can't see how it would cause any problems.  I've chained three GA trackers on one site and had no issues at all.

For more info see here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=4513592e18b05514&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the info, nageeb! Did you include the complete tracking script three times, or just the `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);` line I mentioned above?

Comment: At the time I wasn't sure, so I believe I added the entire script, but that wasn't necessary.  See the link I just posted in the answer for more info.